# How to return to previous activity once finish recording video

Tags: android, video, camera

how can I return back to the previous activity once finish recording video ? , In my situation If I captured video then two options shown " Save" and " Discard"... . I want to remove these option and back to previous activity automatically.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like you want to know how to suppress the 'Save' and 'Discard' options that appear when the default Android video recorder app finishes recording. AFAIK, that's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

call `finish()`  when recording is completed

Comment: This will lead to the activity which was loaded before video recording was started. So here it is better to fire an Intent.

Comment: See the question,How to return to previous activity once finish recording video

Comment: when you can return by doing this why to fire an intent that adds activity to the activity stack

Comment: Oh yes extremely Sorry man you are right finish() will kill the current activity and will return control the previously loaded activity. Again sorry man my mistake.

Comment: I have said you sorry for that and accepted my fault. So stop showing attitude okay.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3174/discussion-between-rocker-and-rasel)

Comment: You said sorry,but didn't withdraw downvote.I told you that.Didn't showing attitude.

Comment: Lets stop this discussion here only man. I dont wanna mess things up.

Comment: who told you to mess things.You can simply withdraw downvote.I guesss, you don't know how to do that.Click again in downvote icon.It will undo downvote.I am feeling sorry for your poor knowledge about SO.

Comment: If your feeling sorry then come and teach me more things about stackoverflow. I think you know each and everything about this website by birth. Am I right Mr stackoverflow.

Comment: I didn't tell that.people are here to help each other.i was asking you to withdraw downvote.But instead you told me "I don't wanna mess things up".See your comment.This is not really a good attitude.See, i told you to remove downvote.Still there is a -1 in my post which is given by you.I told that.But what you did is you lost your temper.We people don't expect that.If you don't know how to do something you can ask.No need to lose temper without proper understanding.Sorry that i hearted you

Answer (score 0):

When Recording gets finished just after that part of code fire an Intent which returns you back to previous activity. Intent firing is done like this ->

1. Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourPreviousActivityName.class);
2. startActivity(intent);

Comment: How can I remove "Save " and "Dicard" options ? any help

Comment: No that is not possible. Save and discard options are by default.